# Checking for email in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Ive looked online and found a lot of questions that are closely related to mine, but nothing that helps solve my problem. Its quite simple, im trying to traverse my table of emails to check if the email exists, if it does not, go ahead and add it. Thing is, it always adds the email, the query does not return anything (even its supposed to). Also im using codeigniter, it that helps or complicate the situation.

Here is the method:

```
public function  add_email(){
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email LIKE '$email'");
        $query->result();
        if($query->num_rows() == 0){
            $data = array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'name' => $this->input->post('name')
            );
            return $this->db->insert('emails', $data);
        } 
        return FALSE;
    }
```

thanks ahead

Comment: If you're checking to see if that exact email address exists, why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=`?

Comment: @PatrickQ Why not? `LIKE` makes the query case-insensitive. It doesn't do any wildcard matching unless you use the wildcard (`%`) operator. And since emails to `Bob@domain.com` are the same as `bob@domain.com`, it makes sense (ignoring the obvious SQL injection vulnerabilities.)

Comment: @sjagr Just seeing if the OP has a good reason for it and isn't perhaps misusing it. Not implying that it is inherently wrong. Also, while most email services do equate email addresses of different cases, technically, `bOB@example.com` is _not_ the same as `Bob@example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done same thing in my project to user login module.

Use below code:-

```
function email_check($srt) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('emails', array('email_id' => $srt), 1);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function add_email() {
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, email, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, name, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    if ($this->email_check($email)) {
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name')
        );
        return $this->db->insert('emails', $data);
    } else {
        echo 'email already exit';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stating that you lowercase your mails ([and you validate your post data](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)) before inserting them to the database, you can do the following

In your **controller**

```
$data = array(
    'email' => strtolower($this->input->post('email')),
    'name'  => $this->input->post('name')
);

$this->model_name->add_email($data);
```

In your **model**

```
public function add_email($data) {

    $this->db->where('email', $data['email']);
    $this->db->from('emails');

    if($this->db->count_all_results() == 0) {

        return $this->db->insert('emails', $data);
    } else {

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```